# Cannot find a particular contributor in the commits

Tags: git, github

My Organization has a private repo on github.com

Now there are bunch of users and i can see them contribute and every commit they make with their respective username which is hyper linked to their profiles.

But there is one user i cannot see the hyper link his name shows in [username] but does not have a hyperlink

Can anyone tell be why?

Regards
Wenceslaus Dsilva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I just did some tests and it seems that GitHub now relies on the email address only to figure out the user. So that's probably where you should look, as @Stefan suggested.

The best thing to do in my opinion is to ask your coworkers to add their (organization?) email address (`git config user.email`) to their [GitHub account](https://github.com/settings/emails).

Another solution would be changing their email address to their GitHub one (`git config --global user.email my@email.com`), but the first solution is much better.

---

That's because their Git `user.name` doesn't match their GitHub username.

What needs to be done is:

```
git config --global user.name MyGitHubUsername
```

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the GitHub user's email doesn't match the commit author's email.

From the [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user):

> GitHub uses the email saved in a commit's header to link the commit to a GitHub user. If you find your commits are being blamed on another user, or not linked to a user at all, you should check your settings.